# Can I view my answer, to a question that was deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I have had a look for answers, couldn’t find one quite right..

Someone posted a fairly bad question, but it made me summarise my views on the topic in answering, and I'd really like to be able to view my answer. Nothing shows up when I search, so I guess either the questioner or moderators deleted the question. Is there any way to view my answer?

The question was about IQ, and my answer was about the greater importance for society of supporting neurodiversity than of coercive or immoral ways of advantaging IQ.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any user, even without the privilege of viewing other people's deleted posts, can see their own deleted answers and the question on which they are placed, if they have the URL for the answer or the question on which it was placed.

You can find the URL for your deleted answers from:

- If you don't clear your browser history, then you can often find the URL to the question and/or answer in your browser history.
- There is a "recently deleted answers" link at the bottom of the ["Answers" tab in your profile](//philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=answers). There's also a "recently deleted questions" link at the bottom of the ["Questions" tab in your profile](//philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=answers). The pages to which those links go show only posts which were deleted within the last 60 days.
- The [access to moderator tools privilege](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) includes being able to view all deleted posts and [search for your own deleted posts](//philosophy.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Amine+deleted%3A1). Non-moderators with the view deleted posts privilege can only search for their own deleted posts. Moderators can search for any deleted posts by any user. You can control if the results of your search include deleted posts by including one of the terms `deleted:yes`, `deleted:1`, `deleted:any`, `deleted:no`, or `deleted:0` in the terms for which you are searching, depending on what you want to see (`deleted:no` is the default).
- If you're unable to find the URL using any of those methods, then you'd need to contact a moderator. This can be done either by raising a flag or asking on Meta. Which is the most appropriate will depend on what's normal for your site. Obviously, flags provide more privacy, but it may be more difficult to communicate exactly what you're looking for in the space available for a flag. If a moderator is unsure as to what you want, the number of deleted posts which you have may make it impossible to provide a list in the *very* limited space available in the custom response area a moderator has for replying to a flag.
- If for some reason all of that fails, then you can either A) use the ["Contact" link](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) at the bottom of any page and request links to your deleted posts, or B) submit a GDPR data request, which should include all of your posts.

Answer (score 1):

I think you refer to [this answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/81298/does-low-average-iq-of-a-population-mean-that-they-cant-create-prosperous-socie/81304#81304).

Generally, all of your answers, including deleted ones, should be accessible through the activity tab of your community profile page.